# change background color in zsh (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: shell, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I installed the zsh package. So, now when I type `zsh` in terminal it switches from bash to zsh.

Also, I downloaded the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) framework to customize zsh. When I change theme name in `.zshrc` file to one of the themes given [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes), it changes the color/type of prompt among other things but the background color stays the same. I want the background color to change to the ones given on that theme wiki page.

So, how do I do change the background color automatically to the ones on that page whenever I change my theme?

Comment: As a side note, `chsh` will let you switch your shell completely so you don't need to run `zsh` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the background color should dependent on your terminal emulator.

This answers some questions using setterm:

[Change the background color in Gnome terminal through a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263892/change-the-background-color-in-gnome-terminal-through-a-command)

Another link for xterm:

[xterm: how to change the background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364017/xterm-how-to-change-the-background-color)